# Amount of Wikidata entries in a given language

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

I wonder how can I found out how many labels in Wikidata are for each language, out of the total amount of 50 millions entries.

For example, in https://query.wikidata.org ,  for Catalán language ("ca") I tried with

```
SELECT ?lang (COUNT(DISTINCT ?item) AS ?count) WHERE {
  ?item schema:inLanguage "ca" .
} GROUP BY ?lang
ORDER BY DESC (?count)
```

and got a result of 703351, but I think it's not correct because I downloaded the Wikidata dump (from https://dumps.wikimedia.org/wikidatawiki/entities/ ), and I already extracted more than two millions of labels in Catalán (and the extraction process is still running)

So, any clue on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your query, you are counting the number of linked articles from the Catalan Wikipedia. Your query should be like `SELECT (count(*) AS ?count) WHERE {
  ?item rdfs:label ?label . filter (lang(?label) = "ca") .
} `. Unfortunately, this falls into timeout. See this statistics: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/User:Pasleim/Language_statistics_for_items

Comment: `SELECT ?lang (COUNT(DISTINCT ?item) AS ?count) WHERE {
  ?item rdfs:label ?label.
  BIND(LANG(?label) as ?lang)
} GROUP BY ?lang
ORDER BY DESC (?count)` - but clearly, too expensive on Wikidata public endpoint...

Comment: you can donwload the dump and use a combination of  `grep`, `awk` `uniq` and `wc -l`

Comment: @AKSW As you can read in the question, I already downloaded the dump and I'm processing it to extract several properties. The processing has been running since friday afternoon (so, more than three days), I just wanted to find a way to get that  stat faster :)

Comment: @StanislavKralin Good one! I surfed through the stats but didn't find that one! Thanks :D

Comment: https://quarry.wmflabs.org/query/27974, https://quarry.wmflabs.org/query/27975

Comment: Thanks @StanislavKralin! Add it as an answer if you want, so I can mark my question as solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the notes above, using Quarry:

https://quarry.wmflabs.org/query/27976

```
USE wikidatawiki_p; 
DESCRIBE wb_terms;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wb_terms
WHERE term_type = 'label' AND term_language = "ca";
```